# Delete duplicated words separated by comma

Tags: python

I am new in python and I have a text file with the following content

> ss ss1, ss ss2, ss ss3, ss ss2, ss ss2, ss ss3

I want to delete the duplicate Words. My expected output is following

> ss ss1, ss ss2, ss ss3

I am using the below code

```
f = open('a.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
words = file_contents.split()
SS=",".join(sorted(set(words), key=words.index))
print SS
```

My current output is

> ss,ss1,,ss2,,ss3,,ss2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the order of the list, you can try this:

```
>>> f="ss ss1, ss ss2, ss ss3, ss ss2, ss ss2, ss ss3"
>>> list(set( f.split(', ')))
['ss ss2', 'ss ss3', 'ss ss1']
```

Constructing `set` from `list` may take a lot time, another way to keep the order:

```
>>> f="ss ss1, ss ss2, ss ss3, ss ss2, ss ss2, ss ss3"
>>> result=[]
>>> for i in f.split(', '):
...     if i not in result:
...         result.append(i)
...
>>> result
['ss ss1', 'ss ss2', 'ss ss3']
```

---

By the way, if the list is very large, and to use `set` to check if new item already exist is a more efficient way.

```
>>> result=[]
>>> s=set()
>>> for i in f.split(', '):
...     if i not in s:
...         result.append(i)
...         s.add(i)
...
>>> result
['ss ss1', 'ss ss2', 'ss ss3']
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Also,  If the number of elements is too high, you could add an additional set so the check for existence of elements. That way `if i not in result` is `o(log n)` in instance of `o(n)`

Comment: @McGrady thanks for your help. If I want retain the the new lines then how I change your code

Comment: @Kevin Maybe you want [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)